# Vertically align the p tag to middle

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I need to align the text inside the p tag to vertically middle. Since I have given height for the p tag the single line text is vertically aligned to the top of the p tag but when there is 2 lines of description it is perfect.

Height 30px should remains the same. I am ending the content to 2 lines so height should be the same.

Here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/1/

Comment: I usually use padding and unfixed height like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/1/ - il will keep centered one line too

Comment: Hi sowymya can you show us the image or screenshot of your exact requirement what exactly you are looking.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey now you can define **line-height:30px**

as like this

```
p.event_desc{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.76);
    padding:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0; width:93%; height:30px;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/10/

Comment: @Sowmya remove your height and do this check to demo http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/20/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
p.event_desc{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.76);
    padding:10px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0; 
    width:93%; 
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define the **line height** and that will work fine with your demo.

Your example is also working fine when i have implemented line-height in your code.

```
p.event_desc{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.76);
    padding:4px;
    top: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: bold 12px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0; width:93%; height:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can throw in an empty img into the `p` tag
e.g:

```
<img style="height:38px;" align="middle"/>
```

(The height of the image is the height plus the margin of your `p` )

[jsFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/ydFy5/11/)